# SwiftUi horizontal Scrollview with data from Api

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-list

I need to make a horizontal Scrollview with data loaded from api.
I have a view like this:

```
 ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators:false) {

      HStack(spacing: 20) {
        ForEach(self.images, id: \.self) { item in

                URLImage(URL(string:item)!)
                               { proxy in
                                   proxy.image
                                       .resizable()
                               }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 120, height: 200).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                               .cornerRadius(15)
                               .opacity(0.7)


    }

    }.onAppear(perform: loadData)

}.padding(.all,20)
```

When I remove scrollview, data is loading perfectly.Any suggestion for this?Thanks

Comment: What happens when you move the .onAppear modifier to the ScrollView instead of the HStack?

Comment: @unequalsine nothing, white screen

Comment: an Apple bug....i could reproduce your error

Comment: @Chris any solution for this bug ?

Comment: just a workaround: load your images before you show the view....

Comment: @Chris thanks, i will try this

Comment: @Chris its not working, can you show me a working example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

this is a quick and dirty example... ;)

```
var imageLoader = ImageLoader()

class ImageLoader {

    var images : [Image] = []

    init() {
        loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {

        for _ in 0..<10 {
            images.append( Image(systemName: "circle.fill"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

       var body: some View {

        ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators:false) {

        HStack(spacing: 20) {

                ForEach(0..<imageLoader.images.count, id: \.self) { item in

                    imageLoader.images[item]
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 120, height: 200).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                        .opacity(0.7)
                }
            }.background(Color.yellow)
        }.background(Color.orange)
    }
}
```